# receiving array of data using UART arduino

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

i am trying to send data through UART in arduino to fingerprint scanner 
i am using an array to send the commands and it works fine

```
for(i =0 ; i<= 24 ; i++)
  {
    Serial.write(SendArray[i]); 
    SendArray[i] =0;
  }
```

the problem is when i'm trying to receive response from the fingerprint 
the fingerprint response is 24 bytes so i tried to receive the bytes and store them in an array of 24 elements

```
 for(k=0 ; k<=24 ; k++)
    {
       RecieveArray[k] = Serial.read();

    }
```

but when i try to print an element from the received array i get strange symbols

Comment: what are the types of `Serial`, `SendArray` and `RecieveArray`? and what does `Serial.read()` return?

Comment: What protocol are you using with he scanner?  What did you expect to receive and how are you detecting/displaying the ' strange symbols'?   Note that you seem to be sending/requesting 25 chars?

Comment: `Serial.read()` returns an `int` and `Serial.write` is used to send binary data, so if you try to visualize directly this data you will see non-printable characters.
Either post-process the received data to convert it into ASCII numbers or manage the communications with `chars`

Comment: both of them are char type 
for example the command is like this 
char SendArray[24] =    {85,170,36,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,1};
and i will receive something like that also

Comment: @MartinJames the scanner is using UART and i expect the receive something like this 

{85,170,36,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,1};
it's on decimal or HEX it doesn't matter 
and i displaying them by storing for example char store = RecieveArray[5]; then i use Serial.println(store); to see the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Serial.read()` in a loop will return `-1` if no data is available, or while data is still being transferred over the serial wire. You are probably filling your buffer with `-1` on that reception loop.

What you can do is wait for `Serial.available()` to become greater than zero before calling `Serial.read()`:

```
for(k = 0; k < 24; k++) {
    while (Serial.available() == 0);
    ReceiveArray[k] = Serial.read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP is trying to work with 24 elements, but is looping 25 times in two places.  Certainly leading to an invalid array access.

```
char SendArray[24] = ...

// for(i =0 ; i<= 24 ; i++)
for(i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  Serial.write(SendArray[i]); 
  SendArray[i] = 0;
}

// for(k=0 ; k<=24 ; k++)
for(k = 0; k < 24; k++)
  RecieveArray[k] = Serial.read();  // Receive spelled wrong
```

Comment: it doesn't work still get unreadable characters

Comment: @Muhammed Ashraf "doesn't work" is not useful. "still get unreadable characters" is not as helpful as posting what out you did receive, what was expected and the minimal code that does that is useful.

Comment: for example i sent {85,170,36,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,1} this sequence of data for the fingerprint .. the fingerprint should reply with ack like this {0x55,0xAA,0x02,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x01}
i should store this sequence to do operations on it for example i have to save 0x01 as a user id 
i tried to store for example element #3 of array in variable of type char then print it using serial.print(); to see and know what it's value 
i get this 
[link](http://i.imgur.com/zwCZQ0h.png)

Comment: @Muhammed Ashraf  Your sender/receiver may have mis-matched word length, parity or stop-bits settings.  Review the ports' set-ups at both ends to insure word-length = 8, same parity, stop bit settings.  Another potential is that the voltage level of the signals are incompatible as you are mostly dropping 1 bits.  This can happen when the sender's voltage is not negative enough.